# How can I prove that $\sum_n \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Clearly $\sum_n \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3$ converges, but I am having an embarrassingly hard time proving it.

I tried the Cauchy Root test, leading me to prove that $\limsup \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1} \right)^\frac{3}{n}=1$, implying that the root test cannot be used. Since the ratio test is equivalent to the root test, I cannot use that either.

I also had the idea of showing that $\frac{2}{n^3}>\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I have no idea how to show that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could show that the summand behaves like $\frac{1}{n^3}$ for large $n$, then apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had to first prove $0< \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3 < \frac{8}{n^3}$. By induction, I showed $-n^2+n < 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You can algebraically manipulate $-n^2+n < 2$ to get $\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3 < \frac{8}{n^3}$. It is also clear that  $0<\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3< \frac{8}{n^3}$. Since $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^3}$ converges, then $\sum_n \frac{8}{n^3}$ converges. Therefore since $0<\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3 < \frac{8}{n^3}$ and $\sum_n \frac{8}{n^3}$ converges, then by the Comparison test $\sum_n \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^3$ converges.

Comment: This is a very general technique.  Look at the leading terms in the numerator and denominator.  As long as the denominator has more than one factor of $n$ greater than the numerator it converges.

Comment: You really need the implication pointing the other direction! Currently you have the inequality you want $\implies$ a true statement. What you want is a true statement $\implies$ the inequality you want. This is the [Fallacy of affirming the consequent!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you, I edited it.

Comment: $0<(n+1)/(n^2+1)\le (2n)/(n^2+1)<(2n)/(n^2)=2/n$ for $n\in \Bbb Z^+.$

Comment: Slightly better is $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\lt\frac1{n-1}$, and start summing from $n=2$.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler: not after cubing

Answer (score 0):

Another useful technique in those cases is the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ for suitable $\alpha$. Sometimes limits are more immediate than inequalities.